# How to clone a built-in Initiative definition policy in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

How do I clone a built-in Initiative definition policy in Azure?

I want to be able to add/remove policies from the built-in "[Preview]: Audit NIST SP 800-53 R4 controls and deploy specific VM Extensions to support audit requirements" initiative policy.

I don't see any option to do this in the Azure Console or PowerShell. I want to avoid manually adding the 798 individual policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, you could use the command to export the policies to a json file.

```
$source = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Id "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/cf25b9c1-bd23-4eb6-bd2c-f4f3ac644a5f"
$source.Properties.policyDefinitions | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Out-File C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\definitions.json
```

You could add/remove policies in the json file, then follow the Example 2 in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicysetdefinition?view=azps-2.8.0#examples) to create the new custom policy set definition.

**Sample**:

```
New-AzPolicySetDefinition -Name "joytest123" -PolicyDefinition C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\definitions.json -Parameter '{ "logAnalyticsWorkspaceIdforVMReporting": { "type": "String" }, "listOfResourceTypesWithDiagnosticLogsEnabled": { "type": "Array" }, "listOfMembersToExcludeFromWindowsVMAdministratorsGroup": { "type": "String" }, "listOfMembersToIncludeInWindowsVMAdministratorsGroup": { "type": "String" }}'
```

[image]

**Note**: Different from the built-in set definition, there is a `500` limit in the custom policy set definition, so you need remove the policies to at least `500`, otherwise you will get an error.  If you need use the other policies, you may create two set definitions with two json file.

[image]

After creating the set definition, you could assign it with [`New-AzPolicyAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-2.8.0) or in the portal.

Comment: Not sure if I missed something. I exported the policies to `definitions.json`, and then split up the policies in half to combat the 500 limit, but get an error. New-AzPolicySetDefinition : InvalidPolicySetDefinitionGroups : The policy set definition 'CustomNIST1' request is invalid. The following group names are referenced but do not exist in the policy set: 'NIST_SP_800-53_R4_IA-2(1),NIST_SP_800-53_R4_IA-2(2),NIST_SP_800-53_R4_SI-2,NIST_SP_800-53_R4_AC-4,....

Comment: @leeman24 You could not remove the policies which are referenced in another policy, you need to put them in the same json file.